# OpenMP: dynamic size array in omp_lock_t?

Tags: c, openmp

My objective is to limit threads access to a single element of an array to one thread at a time. For this purpose I use OpenMP lock primitives. However, what if the Num_Items is dynamic and unknown prior to the code compilation? It seems that omp_lock_t only accepts a static size array as input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int Num_Items = 50; //array size
    int array[Num_Items];
    omp_lock_t lock[Num_Items];
    int val, item, i;

    // initialize locks
    for (i=0; i<Num_Items; i++)
        omp_init_lock(&(lock[i]));

#pragma omp parallel for default(none) private(i, val, item) shared(array, lock, Num_Items)
     for (i=0; i<Num_Items; i++) {
        val= omp_get_thread_num();
        item = (i * 10) % Num_Items ;

        omp_set_lock(&(lock[item]));
        array[item] = val;    // only one thread has access to array[item]
        omp_unset_lock(&(lock[item]));
    }

    // print array[]
    for (i=0; i<Num_Items ; i++)
        printf("array[%i] = %i \n", i, array[i]);

    // destroy locks
    for (i=0; i<Num_Items ; i++)
        omp_destroy_lock(&(lock[i]));


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you precise your problem? There is compile problem because it makes no sense to declare a constant like Num_Items as shared, but once fixed the code compiles and runs properly with gcc and clang.

Comment: @AlainMerigot In the above code the "omp_lock_t lock[Num_Items]" works because Num_Items is set to 50. But if the value of Num_Items is variable, let say we pass it through argv, then visual studio mark it as error and says "expression must have a constant value".

Comment: Even with with a variable Num_Items, there is no problem with gcc or clang. Variable length arrays are supported since C99 and visual should support it. And indeed there is no difference in the compiler point of view between the declarations of `array` and of `lock`.

Comment: Actually after a double check, I was wrong. Visual C does not seem to support VLA. You must use malloc()/free() or alloca().

Comment: @AlainMerigot Thank you Alain. I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

We can allocate a dynamically-sized array with size of omp_lock_t, in case the number of items is unknown prior to the code compilation:

```
omp_lock_t *lock = (omp_lock_t *)malloc(Num_Items*sizeof(omp_lock_t));
```